# C++ Reading a file line by line with delimiter and store data into a list

Tags: c++, list, file, push-back

I have a class called Task that have

```
//Attributes


int earliestStartingTime, earliestEndTime, latestStartingTime, latestEndTime, duration, differ;
char TaskPosition;
list<Task*> predecessors;
list<Task*> successors;


//Constructor

 Task::Task(char TaskPosition2, int duration, list<Task*> predecessors)
 {
      this-> TaskPosition = TaskPosition2;
      this -> duration = duration; 
      for(list<Task*>::iterator it = this-> predecessors(); it != this->predecessors.end(); it++)
      {
           this-> predecessors.push_back(*it);
      }
  }
```

I am trying to read a file line by line and store the data into the list task.

In the file, the data are store as this

A(3)

B(4),A

C(2),A

E(5),A

G(3),A

J(8),B,H

H(7),C,E,G

I(6),G

F(5),H

M(4),I
...

And I want to be able to add them in the list of Task as the following

Task(char TaskPosition, int duration, list predecessors) 
so for example:

A is the task position

3  is the duration

No predecessors

B is the task position

4 is the duration

A  is the predecessor

... 
J is the task position

8 is the duration

B,H  are the predecessors of J

and so on.

I will apply some calculation later to that list such as, what's the shortest way to get from A to Z etc....

But I am still stuck at reading the file and adding them to the list.

This is what I have so far.

```
   int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])

   {
    string line;
    list< Task>* allTask  = new list<Task>;

    const string file = "Test01.txt";  // text file


    ifstream file;

    if(file.is_open())
    {
       while(getline(file, line, ','))
       {
           allTask.push_back(line);     
        }
    }
 }
```

This line

```
    allTask.push_back(line);
```

is giving me an error message that

```
  the lest side of .push_back must have class/struct/union
```

So I am not sure anymore what to do. Anyone can please help me figure out how to read the file add the data into the list please.

Thank you

Comment: `list< Task>* allTask  = new list<Task>;` Repeat after me, slowly and with feeling: C++ is not Java (or C#). There is no need for `new` or a pointer here (and that is what's messing you up: using a pointer, then expecting it to act like an object syntactically).

Answer (score 1):

`allTask` is a pointer so you have to use `->` to use member function directly.  Instead of changing that though there is no reason to have `allTask` as a pointer.  You can simply use

```
list< Task> allTask;
```

And now `allTask` is an automatic object and you can use `.` to call it's member functions.

Answer (score 0):

You might do well reading up and possibly using a serialization deserialization library. This will do exactly what you require and it will give you insight in how to do it in a conventional way.